# How To select and object of label , If it is a child of Grid in C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a program in which I have to change text of label (on the click of button) which is a child of a grid

```
public class XLabel
{
 Grid uiGrid = null;
 TextBlock textblock = null;
 string emptyString = "";

 Public void createLabel()
 {
  uiGrid.Children.Add(textblock);   
  grid.Children.Add(uiGrid);     
 }

 public void cleartext()
 {                
  textblock.Text = emptyString;          
 }
}
```

In other class I have a method to clear text

```
public void clearText()
{         
  XLabel obj = new XLabel();
  obj.cleartext(indexi);          
}
```

How to select specific label to clear text from specific grid if there are many grids and each having one label .

Comment: Your question is a little vague. We need more information about your grid structure, what do you really mean by **select specific label** ? What is your current method doing that is **wrong**? Also, please try and put code in your question that is neatly formatted without spaces, makes it easier for others to check.

Comment: Hello Gideon , i want to add it in a grid as my program have many ui and all of them are placed in a grid . i have selected specific grid but how to get into it's child property. And Specific label was also a problem i solved it ... but only i need to get object of label so i can fix it's properties

Answer (score 1):

The Grid object has properties like *Name* or *Tag*, that can be used for searching.

If you create grids programmatically, you should create a unique property for each, then in your clearText method you just receive all Grid objects from XLabel object and search for the one with proper name/tag.

---

To get a list of labels from grid, you could use lambda like that:

```
List<UIElement> list = 
          YourGrid.Children.Where(o => o.GetType() == typeof(Label)).ToList();
```

Comment: Updated answer. Don't forget to cast your UIElement to Label type.

Answer (score 1):

To extend Olter's answer,

Create your Textblock and Grid like this

```
Grid uiGrid = new Grid() { Name = "uiGrid"+1 };
TextBlock textblock = new TextBlock() { Name = "textBlock"+1 };
```

Each time change the number you add to the grid and textblock and somehow plan to keeptrack of that number.

Then when you want to clear the text,

```
(this.FindName("textBlock"+1) as TextBlock).Text = "";
```

Comment: Its FindName() .. that was a typo